# Sftp : local is remote?

Tags: ssh, remote, sftp

I am trying to remotely connect to University to do some maths simulations, for which I am proceeding by...

```
ssh -X mouser@remoteIPaddress
```

then

```
sftp mouser@remoteIPaddress
```

All connections are okay, but the problem I have is that local is identical to remote. 
Hitting ls correctly lists the remote files in the current directory. 
However lls does not list the local files - it list the remote files.

Have I missed something out in connecting or is there a way I can resolve this so that local is actually local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running those two commands in sequence in the same terminal, what is happening is that you are `ssh`ing from your local machine into the host at `remoteIPaddress`, with X11 forwarding, and then, from an `ssh` session at `remoteIPaddress`, opening an interactive `sftp` session to the same host.  To that `sftp` session, since it was originated within a shell at `remoteIPaddress`, that is the host considered to be local.

What you probably are intending to do is to open `sftp` from a second terminal on your actual local machine.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to SFTP into a remote server, do not SSH into the server before running the SFTP user@server command. Directly run the SFTP user@server from Shell instead.